# value unary ~ org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using unary operations in spark Scala dataframe.

Below is my code.

.when(((a("b) != a("c")) && (~ a("d").isNull()) && (~ a("e").isNull())) , "action")

value unary_~ is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column

I am not able to find solutions in https://spark.apache.org/docs/ also.

Any help is mostly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala use **`!`** (or) `not` to negotiate the result.

**`Example:`**

```
val a = Seq(("a","b","c","p"),("b","d","b","g"),("e","f","f",null.asInstanceOf[String])).toDF("e","b","c","d")

a.withColumn("cw", when( (col("b") !== a("c")) && (!(col("d").isNull)) &&(!(col("e").isNull)), "action").otherwise(0)).show()

//or

a.withColumn("cw", when( (a("b") !== a("c")) && (not(a("d").isNull)) &&(not(a("e").isNull)), "action").otherwise(0)).show()

//+---+---+---+----+------+
//|  e|  b|  c|   d|    cw|
//+---+---+---+----+------+
//|  a|  b|  c|   p|action|
//|  b|  d|  b|   g|action|
//|  e|  f|  f|null|     0|
//+---+---+---+----+------+
```

Comment: it is throwing error as below : type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.Column required: Boolean

Comment: Looks like ! or not is giving  not results but not giving the expected results of Bitwise Complement(~).